# USB detection issues with Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo Yoga 300

Tags: ubuntu, usb, hardware-detection

I'm running Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 300-11IBR and am having trouble with USB devices being detected.

The primary device in question is a Seagate Wireless Plus external hard drive. This particular drive has swappable interface boards (I'm using the USB3 one which it came with) and the interface board has an LED on it which provides an indication of whether it's going to work or not: if the LED lights when the drive is connected then it will be detected and work; if the LED doesn't light then it won't be detected (even by lsusb).

It appears to exhibit the same behaviour whether connected via USB3 or 2: when connected via USB3 it behaves as above; when connected via USB2 the LED either blinks (as the drive seems to require additional power via another USB cable - which I've lost - when connected via USB2) or doesn't light at all.

A reboot usually, but not always, fixes it: in cases where rebooting helps, the aforementioned LED lights as soon as the machine begins the POST sequence, or sometimes during the shutdown process.

This issue also seems to affect the SD reader: with a card inserted, it is only intermittently detected, so I assume that it is connected via USB internally.

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on and/or how to fix it?

Comment: I would upgrade UEFI if there's one available from the manufacturer.

Comment: After a bit of digging (Googling the UEFI version as reported by 'dmidecode') I found what appears to be a newer UEFI version here: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/downloads/ds118297

It's going to take me a while to test though, as it needs to be run from Windows and I no longer have a Windows install on the machine (I've got a 'dd' image of the SSD before I installed Ubuntu, but it's on a mangled partition: running 'fsck' puts every file into 'lost+found), so I'm going to need to sort that first.